# How to check if a vue object is empty in .vue using v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a for-loop running in vue using v-for that loops through a media object to see if there are images stored. That works correctly, but now I want a div displayed below it saying "There is no media" if the object is empty.  The text "There is no media" always displays though.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
<v-flex>
                            <p><v-flex sm3 v-for="media in current_sample.media"  :key="media.id">
                                <v-btn @click="delete_image(media.id)">[X]</v-btn> <img :src="'https://orderinformation.s3.amazonaws.com/' + media.path" class="rotateImg" />
                            </v-flex>
                                <v-flex sm3 v-if="current_sample.media">There is no media</v-flex>
                            </p>
                        </v-flex>
```

Comment: Test specific property instead of object, like
`v-if="current_sample.media.path !== '' "`

Comment: @Deda I did it now says this error: "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" in console

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) property :

```js
 <v-flex sm3 v-if="!Object.entries(current_sample.media).length">There is no media</v-flex>
```

Comment: That solution only works in browsers which supports ECMA 7+
See my solution which works in all browsers

Comment: @protestator That doesnt work it says "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" now

 <v-flex sm3 v-for="media in current_sample.media"  :key="media.id">
                                        <v-btn @click="delete_image(media.id)">[X] </v-btn> <img :src="'https://orderinformation.s3.amazonaws.com/' + media.path" class="rotateImg PreviewImage" />
                                    </v-flex>
                                    <v-flex sm3 v-if="!Object.entries(current_sample.media).length">There is no media</v-flex>

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys which is compatible with all browsers

```
v-if="Object.keys(obj).length"
```

Comment: It now says "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

 <p>
                                <v-flex sm3 v-for="media in current_sample.media"  :key="media.id" style="float:left;">
                                <v-btn @click="delete_image(media.id)">[X] </v-btn> <img :src="'https://orderinformation.s3.amazonaws.com/' + media.path" class="rotateImg" style="float:left;" />
                            </v-flex>
                                <v-flex sm3 v-if="Object.keys(current_sample.media).length">There is no media</v-flex>
                            </p>

Comment: Try this: v-if="current_sample.media && Object.keys(current_sample.media).length"